# How to on page load start at bottom and then auto scroll to the top?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I am using DIV tags instead of iFrames FYI. I want to show the visitor all of the content that is available. I found this code that will auto scroll on page load to the bottom and then back to the top. BUT I want it to start at the bottom and just scroll to the top. Here's the code I found:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.downAndUp = function(time, repeat){
        var elem = this;
        (function dap(){
            elem.animate({scrollTop:elem.outerHeight()}, time, function(){
                elem.animate({scrollTop:0}, time, function(){
                    if(--repeat) dap();
                });
            });
        })();
    }
})(jQuery);
$("html").downAndUp(1000, 2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So there are a ton of samples that will auto scroll to the bottom of the page on page load. I am looking to do the opposite. Start at the bottom and auto scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

This works with an automatic scroll to the top..

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    // Goes to the bottom onLoad
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());    

    // This animates you back to the top    
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');    
});​
```

If you want to scroll after an event replace the line with `$('body, html')` with something like this:

```
$('someElement').click(function{
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); 
});
```

**EDIT** My jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/NxFaR/2/

Comment: I downloaded the newest from jQuery's website (1.7.2). Here's how I have it attached: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I somehow got your code to work. Thanks so much!!! For some reason it was not pulling in the jquery library right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageScroll() {

    window.scrollBy(0, 1); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 10); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }       
   
 }

function stopScroll() {
    clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.